# Moment Generating Function of a Positive Standard Normal

Tags: probability-theory

I'm trying to calculate the m.g.f. of the positive standard normal random variable X, by which the p.d.f. is $f_X(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$ valid for $x \geq 0$. So:
$$E(e^{tX}) = \int_0^\infty e^{tx} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} e^{-x^2/2}dx $$ $$= \int_0^\infty \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2 -2tx + t^2 - t^2)}dx $$
$$ = e^{t^2/2} \int_0^\infty \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-t)^2}dx = e^{t^2/2} $$
But this is the same m.g.f. as the standard normal, which can't be right. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last integral in your solution is not $1$ (except if $t=0$) since
$$
\int_0^\infty \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\mathrm e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-t)^2}\mathrm dx=\int_{-t}^\infty \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \mathrm e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}\mathrm dx.
$$
If this matters, the actual value of this integral is $2\Phi(t)$, where $\Phi$ denotes the [standard normal CDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution), hence
$$
E[\mathrm e^{tX}]=2\Phi(t)\,\mathrm e^{t^2/2}.
$$